# selenium losses sessions when going to a new page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following to sign in and then go to the page. the code signs me in fine but when i go to the new page the sessions on the logged in user are lost.

I how can solve this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://reg.racingpost.com/mpp/sign_in.sd") 
time.sleep(10)
username = browser.find_element_by_id("input-email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("input-pwd")
username.send_keys("@gmail.com")
password.send_keys("")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='button-sign-in']")


login_attempt.submit()
browser.get("http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=650156&r_d")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are *not waiting for the form submission to be completed*. You should look into using [`WebDriverWait` and a set of built-in expected conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the form submission results.

Comment: perfect - didn't think of that one